# viewControllers in mainStoryboard too small

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode9

I don't understand what's going on here. Everytime I click a different viewController the size will increase on some and decrease on others. Prevents any work to be done at all. If I click on a different viewController half of them go back to normal, but the other half stay like this (see picture) (seems random). No matter what, the viewController I am trying to work on will look like this it seems - it also messes up all the constaints (calling for layout fixes). I have it set to view all controllers as an iPhone 8.[image: mainstoryboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select your ViewController in Storyboard. Change **Simulated Metrics: size** to freeform and then Change height in simulated height to 600 or as per your need.[image: Change Size to freeform]

[image: Set simulated height as per need]

Comment: I have to do this for each one? There's not a way to set them all equal to the width and height of the default iPhone # viewController?

Comment: Command click the required VCs and then you will be able to set value for multiple VCs at once.